# Woocommerce - дополнительная цена за атрибут в вариативном товаре

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть магазин с выбором цвета, материала, размера товара (атрибуты) и нужно реализовать фиксированную надбавку к цене при выборе некоторых материалов.

Единственный способ, который я нашел, это создание сотни вариаций, что очень неудобно. Есть какие-то другие варианты реализации надбавки к цене при выборе определенного материала (атрибута)?

Comment: Вопрос актуален, Если вы нашли решение - поделитесь, пожалуйста

Comment: @PavlonNR Воспользовался "единственным способом", благо на сайте не так много вариативных товаров и вариаций к ним